# Unserialize real escaped JSON string

Tags: php, json, serialization

I am trying to save JSON data into a MySQL DB & PHP. I've used

```
// This is the JSON (from Twitter).
$result = 
Array
(
    [created_at] => Wed, 01 Feb 2012 03:53:25 +0000
    [entities] => Array
        (
            [hashtags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => somehashtag
                            [indices] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 85
                                    [1] => 98
                                )

                        )

                )

$stringForDB = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($result));
```

to serialize.

I can't unserialize it.

I've tried

```
$obj=unserialize($stringForDB);
```

but the $obj is blank.

Comment: Why `serialize`? JSON data already is a string.

Comment: @Gumbo because if I dont I get 'Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in .php'

Comment: Then your `$result` is no valid JSON. Or do you want to encode the array to JSON? Maybe its best to post what `$result` looks like and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Try using `stripslashes() ` before un-serializing it

Comment: you just have given the array output from twitter ,,Give the exact feed url ,,then it is easy to serialize and unserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) will prepend backslashes to ' and " thus making it impossible to unserialize.

```
$serializedResult = serialize($result);

// $stringForDB can not be unserialized since it has extra backslashes
$stringForDB = mysql_real_escape_string($serializedResult));

// Some code to insert $stringForDB into the database

$obj=unserialize($serializedResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$obj=json_decode($stringForDB);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php